# How to keep size of div it's initial height

Tags: html, css

I have a paginated list that I am displaying in a div.

```
<div id="list">
     <item 1 />
     <item 2 />
     <item 3 />
     <item 4 />
     <item 5 />
</div>
```

The paging shows 5 items at a time. Let say for example there are 7 items in the list. With the way I currently have things implemented, the div would start off 5 items big and then when you switch pages `#list` ends up being smaller because there are only 2 items on that page.

My goal is to have it so that `#list` stays its initial size despite the number of items on the second page. So, if `#list` is height 250px (for example) with 5 items, the second page should also be height 250px.

I can't necessarily do

```
#list {
     min-height: 250px;
}
```

because that won't work on smaller screens when text starts to wrap. What direction should I go from here?

Comment: you have to define your behaviour. set the min-height or max-height or a fixed height based on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If your reason for not using min-height lies on the differences when presenting on smaller screens, then you could specify a height relative to the viewport size.  Use either "%" or "vh",  and additionally set the list to overflow if needed. Perhaps something like:

```
#list {
  min-height: 40vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to set a CSS property for smaller screens only.